# Spring Boot Java Read multiple Locations separated by ; instead of only one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, import

How can I read more Locations from the imported file separated by ; do I need to change the searchByName function as well?

```
 @Override
    public String getData(Row rowData, int index) {
        final Cell cell = rowData.getCell(index);
        if ((cell != null) && ((CellType.STRING == cell.getCellType()) || (CellType.FORMULA == cell.getCellType()))) {
            return StringUtils.trimToNull(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
private Location getLocation(Row rowData, int index, String prefix) {
        String nomLocation= this.excelReaderService.getData(rowData, index);
        
        Location location= this.locationService.searchByName(nomLocation);

        return location;
    }
```

```
  @Override
    public Location searchByName(String name) {
        return this.locationRepository.findFirstByName(name).orElse(null);
    }
```

Comment: incomprehensible question... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, I'd first create a new method called `getLocations` to return a `List<Location>`.  Inside that, I'd `split` on the semi-colon to get a String array of locations.  I'd also convert that array to a `List<String>` as those are easier with work with when dealing with repository methods :

```
private List<Location> getLocations(Row rowData, int index, String prefix) {
    String locationData= this.excelReaderService.getData(rowData, index);
    String[] nomLocations = locationData.split(";");
    List<String> locationsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(nomLocations));

    List<Location> locations= this.locationService.searchByNames(locationsList);

    return locations;
}
```

Then, I'd create a new method in the Locations Service called `searchByNames`.  How you build that method depends on what your underlying database is.  If it's a **relational** database, you might be able to use the JPA query method for an `IN` clause:

```
@Override
public List<Location> searchByNames(List<String> names) {
    return this.locationRepository.findByNameIn(names);
}
```

You would, of course, also have to define that method in your Location Repository interface:

```
List<Location> findByNameIn(List<String> names);
```

On the other hand, if you're using a **NoSQL** database, querying with an `IN` clause is usually an anti-pattern.  In that case, you'd want to build the new `searchByNames` method iterate through the list and make multiple calls to the repository method:

```
@Override
public List<Location> searchByNames(List<String> names) {
    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Location location : locations) {
        Location result = this.locationRepository.findFirstByName(name).orElse(null);

        if (result != null) {
            locations.add(result);
        }        
    }

    return locations;
}
```

Hope this helps!